# Facebook profile sometimes misses timezone attribute

Tags: json, facebook, timezone, profile

I run a web app that makes use of facebook connect. Recently, the profile information for few users does not contain the timezone attribute anymore.

Normally, going to the page https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=0123456789 (correct access token link can be found on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) looks something like the following.

```
{
    "id": "1234567890",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1234567890",
    "birthday": "05/23/1984",
    "work": [
       {
        ...
       }
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "timezone": -5,
    "locale": "us_US",
    "updated_time": "2011-04-15T20:41:33+0000"
 }
```

Any ideas why the *"timezone": -5* part could go missing? This changes for existing users, without a change in permissions.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I see my own timezone. Well, they always change their API, maybe this is just another bug. Report to Facebook and see what they say...

Answer (score 1):

Quite odd: if the user doesn't have a location specified, changes their location at or around the time you are hitting the API or logs in from computers with varying timezones it is quite possible they won't have timezone info.